How can I avoid Python overflow in pytorch tensors? EDIT: A tensor insiede softmax function suddely become nan after the second iteration
I'm working with really big tensors from pytorch, and as a result of a certain operation I need my tensor to maintain really big values(which represent some indexes), but obviously overflow makes all numbers in the tensor assume the value -9223372036854775808.
This is the repo https://github.com/SamuelMastrelli/neural-astar. When I try to launch train_maps.py, the outputs clearly indicates me some overflow[EDIT:this happens because idx become a set of nan fro some reason]:
scripts/train_maps.py:21: UserWarning: 
The version_base parameter is not specified.
Please specify a compatability version level, or None.
Will assume defaults for version 1.1
  @hydra.main(config_path="config", config_name="train_maps")
GPU available: True (cuda), used: True
TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
IPU available: False, using: 0 IPUs
HPU available: False, using: 0 HPUs
Missing logger folder: model/maps/lightning_logs
LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0]

  | Name          | Type         | Params
-----------------------------------------------
0 | planner       | NeuralAstar  | 391 K 
1 | vanilla_astar | VanillaAstar | 9     
-----------------------------------------------
391 K     Trainable params
18        Non-trainable params
391 K     Total params
1.566     Total estimated model params size (MB)
Sanity Checking: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/connectors/data_connector.py:224: PossibleUserWarning: The dataloader, val_dataloader 0, does not have many workers which may be a bottleneck. Consider increasing the value of the `num_workers` argument` (try 8 which is the number of cpus on this machine) in the `DataLoader` init to improve performance.
  rank_zero_warn(
Sanity Checking DataLoader 0:   0%|                       | 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/functional.py:478: UserWarning: torch.meshgrid: in an upcoming release, it will be required to pass the indexing argument. (Triggered internally at  ../aten/src/ATen/native/TensorShape.cpp:2894.)
  return _VF.meshgrid(tensors, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
parent1:  tensor([[64118., 64118., 64118.,  ..., 64118., 64118., 64118.]],
       device='cuda:0')
idx:  tensor([[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]], device='cuda:0')
newparents:  tensor([[17658]], device='cuda:0')
parent2:  tensor([[64118., 64118., 64118.,  ..., 64118., 64118., 64118.]],
       device='cuda:0')
idx:  tensor([[nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan]], device='cuda:0')
newparents:  tensor([[0]], device='cuda:0')
parent2:  tensor([[nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan]], device='cuda:0')
tensor([-9223372036854775808], device='cuda:0')
torch.Size([1, 90000])
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/IndexKernel.cu:91: operator(): block: [0,0,0], thread: [0,0,0] Assertion `index >= -sizes[i] && index < sizes[i] && "index out of bounds"` failed.
Error executing job with overrides: []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/call.py", line 38, in _call_and_handle_interrupt
    return trainer_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 645, in _fit_impl
    self._run(model, ckpt_path=self.ckpt_path)
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 1098, in _run
    results = self._run_stage()
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 1177, in _run_stage
    self._run_train()
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 1190, in _run_train
    self._run_sanity_check()
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 1262, in _run_sanity_check
    val_loop.run()
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/loop.py", line 199, in run
    self.advance(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/dataloader/evaluation_loop.py", line 152, in advance
    dl_outputs = self.epoch_loop.run(self._data_fetcher, dl_max_batches, kwargs)
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/loop.py", line 199, in run
    self.advance(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/epoch/evaluation_epoch_loop.py", line 137, in advance
    output = self._evaluation_step(**kwargs)
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/epoch/evaluation_epoch_loop.py", line 234, in _evaluation_step
    output = self.trainer._call_strategy_hook(hook_name, *kwargs.values())
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 1480, in _call_strategy_hook
    output = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/strategy.py", line 390, in validation_step
    return self.model.validation_step(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/neural_astar/utils/training.py", line 68, in validation_step
    outputs = self.forward(map_designs, start_maps, goal_maps)
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/neural_astar/utils/training.py", line 53, in forward
    return self.planner(map_designs, start_maps, goal_maps)
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/neural_astar/planner/astar.py", line 207, in forward
    return self.perform_astar(
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/neural_astar/planner/astar.py", line 63, in perform_astar
    astar_outputs = astar(
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/neural_astar/planner/differentiable_astar.py", line 264, in forward
    path_maps = backtrack(start_maps, goal_maps, parents, t)
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/neural_astar/planner/differentiable_astar.py", line 128, in backtrack
    loc = parents[range(num_samples), loc]
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/train_maps.py", line 63, in main
    trainer.fit(module, train_loader, val_loader)
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 603, in fit
    call._call_and_handle_interrupt(
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/call.py", line 63, in _call_and_handle_interrupt
    trainer._teardown()
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 1161, in _teardown
    self.strategy.teardown()
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/strategy.py", line 496, in teardown
    self.lightning_module.cpu()
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lightning_lite/utilities/device_dtype_mixin.py", line 78, in cpu
    return super().cpu()
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 738, in cpu
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cpu())
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 579, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 579, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 602, in _apply
    param_applied = fn(param)
  File "/home/mastrelli/neural-astar/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 738, in <lambda>
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cpu())
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.

Set the environment variable HYDRA_FULL_ERROR=1 for a complete stack trace.

EDIT: What i meant by index is that the value contained in tensor semantically is an index value in my project. I found the issue being the variable idx become a set of nan.
This is the file:
"""Differentiable A* module and helper functions
Author: Ryo Yonetani, Mohammadamin Barekatain 
Affiliation: OSX
"""

from __future__ import annotations

import math
from typing import List, NamedTuple, Optional

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class AstarOutput(NamedTuple):
    """
    Output structure of A* search planners
    """

    histories: torch.tensor
    paths: torch.tensor
    intermediate_results: Optional[List[dict]] = None


def get_heuristic(goal_maps: torch.tensor, tb_factor: float = 0.001) -> torch.tensor:
    """
    Get heuristic function for A* search (chebyshev + small const * euclidean)

    Args:
        goal_maps (torch.tensor): one-hot matrices of goal locations
        tb_factor (float, optional): small constant weight for tie-breaking. Defaults to 0.001.

    Returns:
        torch.tensor: heuristic function matrices
    """

    # some preprocessings to deal with mini-batches
    num_samples, H, W = goal_maps.shape[0], goal_maps.shape[-2], goal_maps.shape[-1]  #numero dei campioni, Altezza e lasrghezza delle matrici
    grid = torch.meshgrid(torch.arange(0, H), torch.arange(0, W))  #griglia con righe 0 a H e colonne da 0 a W
    loc = torch.stack(grid, dim=0).type_as(goal_maps) #Vengono poi stackate insieme con lo stesso tipo di goal_maps
    loc_expand = loc.reshape(2, -1).unsqueeze(0).expand(num_samples, 2, -1) #Ridimensione a 2, -1(ultima dimensione), viene aggiunta la dimensione grande 1 e viene ripetuto per numsamples
    goal_loc = torch.einsum("kij, bij -> bk", loc, goal_maps)  #Somma di einstein:
    #Operazione per generalizzare operazioni tra matrici e tensori(perdiamo un po' di ottimizzazione solo in alcuni casi)
    #Moltiplicazione tra loc e goal maps che ha come dimensioni b e k: se loc e' 4, 5, 5 e goal maps e' 10, 5, 5 -> matrice 4 x 10
    goal_loc_expand = goal_loc.unsqueeze(-1).expand(num_samples, 2, -1) #Aggiunge una dimensione 1 alla fine, espande per num_samples

    # chebyshev distance
    dxdy = torch.abs(loc_expand - goal_loc_expand)  #chebyshev
    h = dxdy.sum(dim=1) - dxdy.min(dim=1)[0] #somma su dimensione - minimo sulla dimensione 1
    euc = torch.sqrt(((loc_expand - goal_loc_expand) ** 2).sum(1)) #distanza euclidea
    h = (h + tb_factor * euc).reshape_as(goal_maps) #euristica con la forma di goal_maps

    return h


def _st_softmax_noexp(val: torch.tensor) -> torch.tensor: #Softmax per trovare il nodo migliore
    """
    Softmax + discretized activation
    Used a detach() trick as done in straight-through softmax

    Args:
        val (torch.tensor): exponential of inputs.

    Returns:
        torch.tensor: one-hot matrices for input argmax.
    """

    val_ = val.reshape(val.shape[0], -1)
    y = val_ / (val_.sum(dim=-1, keepdim=True))
    _, ind = y.max(dim=-1)
    y_hard = torch.zeros_like(y)
    y_hard[range(len(y_hard)), ind] = 1
    y_hard = y_hard.reshape_as(val)
    y = y.reshape_as(val)
    return (y_hard - y).detach() + y


def expand(x: torch.tensor, neighbor_filter: torch.tensor) -> torch.tensor: #Nodi vicini a x, Neighbo filter : [[111], [101], [111]]
    """
    Expand neighboring node

    Args:
        x (torch.tensor): selected nodes
        neighbor_filter (torch.tensor): 3x3 filter to indicate 8 neighbors

    Returns:
        torch.tensor: neighboring nodes of x
    """

    x = x.unsqueeze(0)
    num_samples = x.shape[1]
    y = F.conv2d(x, neighbor_filter, padding=1, groups=num_samples).squeeze()
    y = y.squeeze(0)
    return y


def backtrack(
    start_maps: torch.tensor,
    goal_maps: torch.tensor,
    parents: torch.tensor, #Come funziona?
    current_t: int,
) -> torch.tensor: #Chiedere
    """
    Backtrack the search results to obtain paths

    Args:
        start_maps (torch.tensor): one-hot matrices for start locations
        goal_maps (torch.tensor): one-hot matrices for goal locations
        parents (torch.tensor): parent nodes
        current_t (int): current time step

    Returns:
        torch.tensor: solution paths
    """

    num_samples = start_maps.shape[0]
    parents = parents.type(torch.long)
    goal_maps = goal_maps.type(torch.long)
    start_maps = start_maps.type(torch.long)
    path_maps = goal_maps.type(torch.long)
    num_samples = len(parents)  ##Why?
    loc = (parents * goal_maps.view(num_samples, -1)).sum(-1)
    print(loc)
    print(parents.shape)
    for _ in range(current_t):
        path_maps.view(num_samples, -1)[range(num_samples), loc] = 1
        loc = parents[range(num_samples), loc]
    return path_maps


class DifferentiableAstar(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, g_ratio: float = 0.5, Tmax: float = 1.0):
        """
        Differentiable A* module

        Args:
            g_ratio (float, optional): ratio between g(v) + h(v). Set 0 to perform as best-first search. Defaults to 0.5.
            Tmax (float, optional): how much of the map the planner explores during training. Defaults to 1.0.
        """

        super().__init__()

        neighbor_filter = torch.ones(1, 1, 3, 3)
        neighbor_filter[0, 0, 1, 1] = 0

        self.neighbor_filter = nn.Parameter(neighbor_filter, requires_grad=False)
        self.get_heuristic = get_heuristic

        self.g_ratio = g_ratio
        assert (Tmax > 0) & (Tmax <= 1), "Tmax must be within (0, 1]"
        self.Tmax = Tmax

    def forward(
        self,
        cost_maps: torch.tensor,
        start_maps: torch.tensor,
        goal_maps: torch.tensor,
        obstacles_maps: torch.tensor,
        store_intermediate_results: bool = False,
    ) -> AstarOutput:
        """
        Perform differentiable A* search

        Args:
            cost_maps (torch.tensor): cost maps
            start_maps (torch.tensor): start maps indicating the start location with one-hot binary map
            goal_maps (torch.tensor): goal maps indicating the goal location with one-hot binary map
            obstacle_maps (torch.tensor): binary maps indicating obstacle locations
            store_intermediate_results (bool, optional): If the intermediate search results are stored in Astar output. Defaults to False.

        Returns:
            AstarOutput: search histories and solution paths, and optionally intermediate search results.
        """

        assert cost_maps.ndim == 4
        assert start_maps.ndim == 4
        assert goal_maps.ndim == 4
        assert obstacles_maps.ndim == 4

        cost_maps = cost_maps[:, 0]
        start_maps = start_maps[:, 0]
        goal_maps = goal_maps[:, 0]
        obstacles_maps = obstacles_maps[:, 0]

        num_samples = start_maps.shape[0]
        neighbor_filter = self.neighbor_filter
        neighbor_filter = torch.repeat_interleave(neighbor_filter, num_samples, 0)
        size = start_maps.shape[-1]

        open_maps = start_maps
        histories = torch.zeros_like(start_maps)
        intermediate_results = []

        h = self.get_heuristic(goal_maps)
        h = h + cost_maps 
        g = torch.zeros_like(start_maps)

        parents = (
            #Vettori dei starting point
            torch.ones_like(start_maps).reshape(num_samples, -1)
            * goal_maps.reshape(num_samples, -1).max(-1, keepdim=True)[-1] #vettori dei goal, poi gli indici di essi
        )
        print("parent1: ", parents)

        size = cost_maps.shape[-1]
        Tmax = self.Tmax if self.training else 1.0
        Tmax = int(Tmax * size * size)
        for t in range(Tmax):

            # select the node that minimizes cost
            f = self.g_ratio * g + (1 - self.g_ratio) * h #f di a start con ratio tra g e h
            f_exp = torch.exp(-1 * f / math.sqrt(cost_maps.shape[-1])) #attivazione di hubara, con temperatura come radice della dimensione -1 dei costi [width]
            f_exp = f_exp * open_maps #Scherma con i nodi aperti
            selected_node_maps = _st_softmax_noexp(f_exp) #Selezione nodo migliore
            if store_intermediate_results:
                intermediate_results.append(
                    {
                        "histories": histories.unsqueeze(1).detach(),
                        "paths": selected_node_maps.unsqueeze(1).detach(),
                    }
                )

            # break if arriving at the goal
            dist_to_goal = (selected_node_maps * goal_maps).sum((1, 2), keepdim=True)
            is_unsolved = (dist_to_goal < 1e-8).float()

            histories = histories + selected_node_maps
            histories = torch.clamp(histories, 0, 1) #Min 0, max 1
            open_maps = open_maps - is_unsolved * selected_node_maps
            open_maps = torch.clamp(open_maps, 0, 1)

            # open neighboring nodes, add them to the openlist if they satisfy certain requirements
            neighbor_nodes = expand(selected_node_maps, neighbor_filter)
            neighbor_nodes = neighbor_nodes * obstacles_maps

            # update g if one of the following conditions is met
            # 1) neighbor is not in the close list (1 - histories) nor in the open list (1 - open_maps)
            # 2) neighbor is in the open list but g < g2
            g2 = expand((g + cost_maps) * selected_node_maps, neighbor_filter)
            idx = (1 - open_maps) * (1 - histories) + open_maps * (g > g2)
            idx = idx * neighbor_nodes
            idx = idx.detach()
            g = g2 * idx + g * (1 - idx)
            g = g.detach()

            # update open maps
            open_maps = torch.clamp(open_maps + idx, 0, 1)
            open_maps = open_maps.detach()
 
            # for backtracking
            idx = idx.reshape(num_samples, -1)
            snm = selected_node_maps.reshape(num_samples, -1)
            new_parents = snm.max(-1, keepdim=True)[1]
            print("idx: ", idx)
            print("newparents: ", new_parents)
            parents = new_parents * idx + parents * (1 - idx)
            print("parent2: ", parents)

            if torch.all(is_unsolved.flatten() == 0):
                break

        # backtracking
        path_maps = backtrack(start_maps, goal_maps, parents, t)

        if store_intermediate_results:
            intermediate_results.append(
                {
                    "histories": histories.unsqueeze(1).detach(),
                    "paths": path_maps.unsqueeze(1).detach(),
                }
            )

        return AstarOutput(
            histories.unsqueeze(1), path_maps.unsqueeze(1), intermediate_results
        )

The data: https://github.com/SamuelMastrelli/neural-astar/tree/minimal/src/neural_astar/utils/voronoi_utilities/maps_data/maps
And the training script is :
"""
Training neural A * with maps dataset from 
https://github.com/micheleantonazzi/gibson-env-utilities
"""

from __future__ import annotations

import os

import hydra
import pytorch_lightning as pl 
import torch 
from neural_astar.planner import NeuralAstar
from neural_astar.utils.data_maps import create_dataloader
from neural_astar.utils.training import PlannerModule, set_global_seeds
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import sys
import os


@hydra.main(config_path="config", config_name="train_maps")
def main(config):
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    set_global_seeds(config.seed)
    train_loader = create_dataloader(dir=config.dataset, cluster="train_resized", batch_size=config.params.batch_size)
    val_loader = create_dataloader(dir=config.dataset, cluster="validation_resized", batch_size=config.params.batch_size)

    m, s, g, t = next(iter(train_loader))
    print(m.shape, s.shape, g.shape, t.shape)

    print(m)
    print(s)
    print(g)
    print(t)


  

    neural_astar = NeuralAstar(
        encoder_arch=config.encoder.arch,
        encoder_depth=config.encoder.depth,
        encoder_input=config.encoder.input,
        learn_obstacles=False,
        Tmax=config.Tmax,
    )

 


    checkpoint_callbacks = ModelCheckpoint(
        monitor="metrics/h_mean", save_weights_only=False, mode="max"
    )

    module = PlannerModule(neural_astar, config)
    logdir = f"{config.logdir}/{os.path.basename(config.dataset)}"
    trainer = pl.Trainer(
        accelerator= "gpu" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu",
        log_every_n_steps=1,
        default_root_dir=logdir,
        max_epochs=config.params.num_epochs,
        callbacks=[checkpoint_callbacks],
    )
    trainer.fit(module, train_loader, val_loader)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I added some print, to inspect the value of idx and parent variables

Are you sure that your problem is the overflow of indices, not the index value itself? The maximum value of torch.int64 (before overflowing) is 9223372036854775807, which is approximately 9.2e18. If this index overflows, this implies you have more than 9.2e18 elements in the tensor that you want to index. Assuming this was the index of a torch.int8 tensor (which is one of the smallest available data types), this would imply that your underlying tensor contains more than 9.2 exabytes of data. Is this realistic? Or am I misunderstanding something? Maybe clarify the meaning of your index.

By the way: please do not assume that people look into the code that you linked (your GitHub repo, that is), but rather try to make your question self-contained.

@simon I'm sorry, maybe that information about indexes was not needed. What i mean is that the meaning of the values in that tensor is being an index, but doesnt  matter. As i edited, after  the first iteration the variable idx became nan, and i assume the problem is still overflow, but i'm not sure

Thanks for the clarification and sharing the relevant piece of code. It is still hard to reproduce your problem though, since there is neither data nor program flow that uses it.

@simon I know, i didnt know how to present the problem, thanks for your time though. I edited again, with the script and the folder containing the data

Turns out in the softmax function, in the second iteration suddenly y become full of nan. But the operation is the same with the same value of the previous iteration
